# Can I compare two density matrices of different dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

Given two density matrices of different dimension (constructed in two different bases) is there a way of quantifying their distance (like Quantum Uhlmann fidelity)?

My idea was that one needs to construct a map between the two bases so that we can compute the fidelity with two density matrices of equal dimension.

Comment: What would even be the physical intuition behind *any* kind of such distance measure?

Comment: By constructing a lower-dimensional Hilbert space, the physical intuition would be " how good is the approximation of the lower-dimensional Hilbert space compared to the exact (higher-dimensional) one".

Answer (score 1):

If the density matrices act on different Hilbert spaces, then that means that they describe the state of two different physical systems. Typically the “distance” between two density matrices measures the similarity of two different states of the *same* physical system. If you want to try to compare the states of two different physical systems, then that will necessarily be somewhat subjective and situation-dependent, depending on what kind of similarity you want to capture.

So no, I don’t think there’s any kind of abstract and general purely mathematical framework for doing that.

Comment: Of course you can compare the distance of different physical system, like the state of a two-level atom and the polarization state of a photon.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Well, only if you choose a preferred isomorphism between their Hilbert spaces, right? That’s where the physics comes in; there’s no purely mathematical canonical choice.

Comment: True. To be fair, the question does not talk about whether there is a purely mathematical definition.